# VueJS 2 - Watch properties inside arrays and/or objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/hxv5bLqt/

I have a data structure with 2 levels (arrays). The first level is the "parts", and the second level are the "items", which are inside each "part". There is also a variable that stores the total value of each item's values. The example work is as follows: every time the user types something in some value field, or removes a value, the total must be recalculated.

However, I'm not satisfied with the example solution, since I'll need to be mapping all the places where the "this.recompute()" method should be called, and with watchs or computed properties this could be solved in a clearer way , clean and reactive.

However, I am not able to implement a "watch" or a "computed property" that can see changes in properties of objects that are inside arrays.

For the "watch" case, I imagine that the ideal and what I thought would work is:

```
watch: {
    'parts.X.items.Y.value': function(oldValue, newValue) {
         this.recompute()
    }
}
```

The "X" and the "Y" indicate variables that indicate that the fields to be observed will be in any position of the arrays.

That way, every time the user clicked the button to remove an item, or typed something in the value field, the watch would be triggered. But that does not work.

That way, every time the user clicked the button to remove an item, or typed something in the value field, the watch would be triggered. However this does not work and I am required to be mapping all the points where the "this.recompute()" method should be called, as following:

```
onClickRemoveItem(event, part, item) {
    ...
    this.recompute() // RECOMPUTE HERE.
},

onKeyupItemValue(event) {
    this.recompute() // RECOMPUTE HERE.
},
```

I think this is not a good way to solve the problem, because if there are 10 more places where the "this.recompute()" method should be called, it will be difficult to remember all the call places.

There would be a way to do this in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your total a computed property then you get a lot more reactivity for free (meaning you don't have to listen for updates to the item values or explicitly recalculate anything). See the answer here for specific implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/16wk9gre/

html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Tests</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="part in parts">
      <span>{{ part.name }}</span>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in part.items">
          R$ <input type="number" v-model="item.value">
          <button type="button" @click="onClickRemoveItem($event, part, item)">Remove</button>
        </li>
        <p>
           Part subtotal: ${{ part.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + parseFloat(item.value), 0) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          Part subtotal (alternate): ${{ calculatePartSubtotal(part.items) }}
      </p>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <p><strong>Total value:</strong>R$ {{ total }}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      // Define some nested mock data.
      parts: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Part 1', items: [{ id: 1, value: 10.00 }, { id: 2, value: 5.00 }] },
        { id: 2, name: 'Part 2', items: [{ id: 3, value: 15.00 }] }
      ]
   }
 },
computed: {
  total () {
    let total = 0.0
    for (let i = 0; i < this.parts.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.parts[i].items.length;; j++) {
        total += parseFloat(this.parts[i].items[j].value)
      }
    }
    return total
  }
},
methods: {
  calculatePartSubtotal (items) {
    return items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + parseFloat(item.value), 0)
  },
  // Remove an item of a part.
  onClickRemoveItem(event, part, item) {
    let index = part.items.findIndex(e => e.id === item.id)
    this.$delete(part.items, index)
   }
 }
})
```